# Inductive energy when 12V relay coil is released

Tags: relay, flyback

Maybe this question is non-sense.
If I have a commom 12V relay (12V, 400 ohms coil) WITHOUT having a flyback diode connected to it, and driven by a low-side protected transistor/IC like ZXMS6004FF (the internal over-voltage protection would do the diode job). The datasheet of the transistor shows it withstands to a 90mJ "Unclamped Single Pulse Inductive Energy".

This is for a very specific project question. Would the transistor get damaged?

Datasheet of ZXMS6004FF:
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXMS6004FF.pdf

Answer (score 5):

You need to know the inductance of the relay coil. Then you can calculate the total energy of the coil by \$ E= \frac {1}{2}LI^2 \$ and compare that to 90 mJ.

Answer (score 3):

est.L=4H +/-50%, I=12/400=0.03A \$ E= \frac {1}{2}LI^2 \$ =1.8mJ +/-50%  seems well under 90mJ

Comment: only that 1.8mJ? So the transistor will be ok!

Comment: @abomin3v3l Don't jump to comclusions, he *estimated* L to be 4 H, even if it would need to be considerably greater to do damage. Maybe the word should be emphasized so that a quick glance cannot be tricked.

Comment: Yes, it will be OK and will electrically switch at a much faster rate than with a Vdd diode clamp for dV/dt. The 50% was an estimated tolerance on my estimate.